# how to turn a hapi auth plugin to be optional

Tags: node.js, authentication, hapi.js

I'd like to use the hapi jwt token auth plugin https://github.com/ryanfitz/hapi-auth-jwt but make a route with optional authentication.  How can I prevent the route from returning a 401 and instead continue executing with a null request.auth.credentials.

I'd like all the other routes that are using it to keep the same implementation of returning a 401 on non authenticated requests.

```
server.register(require('hapi-auth-jwt'), function (error) {

    server.auth.strategy('token', 'jwt', {
        key: privateKey,
        validateFunc: validate
    });

    //make this one allow anonymous while also reading logged in credentials
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        config: {
            auth: 'token'
        }
    });

    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/mystuff',
        config: {
            auth: 'token'
        }
    });
});


server.start();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set it to optional in route configuration:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    config: {
        auth: {
            strategy: 'token',
            mode: 'optional'
        }    
    }
});
```

Mode can be `true`, `false`, `required`, `optional`, or `try`. See the [authentication tutorial](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/auth) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Besides the `optional` route's auth configuration, you can also use `try`.

```
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/',
  config: {
    auth: {
      strategy: 'token',
      mode: 'try'
    }    
  }
})
```

The difference between those two

- `optional`: no authentication credentials needed, but if provided they need to be valid
- `try`: if the user provides invalid authentication credentials they still get accepted and users will proceed to the route handler